# How do I do a array group and count it, like in MySQL group by given column id?

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array, duplicates

I have a large array as bellow, now I need to do a group by first column and count the total of that channel existence.

For example:

```
var original_db = [
  ["channel1", "online"],
  ["channel2", "offline"],
  ["channel3", "online"],
  ["channel1", "online"],
  ["lot more"]....
]
```

Expected result from the original result need to be:

```
var custom_db = [
  ["channel1", 2], 
  ["channel2", 0],
  ["channel3", 1]
]
```

EDIT:

```
for(var key in original_db) {
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < original_db.length; i += 1) {
        if (original_db[i][0] === original_db[key][0]) {
            original_db.splice(i, 1);
            return;
        }
    }

}

console.log(original_db);
```

Comment: Please show what you've tried. We're not here to do your work for you, but we'll happily help you fix the problems in your code.

Comment: Please post the code in the question so it's readable. There's no formatting in comments.

Comment: Please see the EDIT section, there i was trying to do two loop but its not helping for the counting if there was how many channels.

Comment: Your loop will splice everything out, because sometimes `key == i`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an object whose properties are the first elements to keep the count:

```
var counts = {};

for (var i = 0; i < original.length; i++) {
    var key = original[i][0];
    if (counts[key]) {
        counts[key]++;
    } else {
        counts[key] = 1;
    }
}
```

You can then turn this into your final array, although I'm not sure why you prefer that over the `counts` object:

```
final = [];
for (var key in counts){
    final.push([key, counts[key]]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert the array to JSON object and do a loop to get the count.

Comment: Why do you need JSON? Just use an ordinary Javascript object.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is a group by, order by in javascript but what you can do create a new array and check if the indexes of channels are set. If it is set, you increment it. If it is not set, and the status is online, you set it to 1, otherwise to 0;

```
var original_db = [
  ["channel1", "online"],
  ["channel2", "offline"],
  ["channel3", "online"],
  ["channel1", "online"]
];

var ordered_arr = {};

for(var i=0;i<original_db.length;i++)
{

 if(ordered_arr[original_db[i][0]])
    ordered_arr[original_db[i][0]]+=1;
 else
   if(original_db[i][1] =="online")
    ordered_arr[original_db[i][0]]=1;
   else
     ordered_arr[original_db[i][0]]=0;
}

console.log(ordered_arr);
```